# Graph API provision of federated user

Tags: office365api

I am unable to provision users to a federated domain, say `example.org`, with [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph).

The url I am sending the POST to is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

json payload is:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "city": "Seattle",
  "country": "United States",
  "department": "Sales & Marketing",
  "displayName": "Melissa Darrow",
  "givenName": "Melissa",
  "jobTitle": "Marketing Director",
  "mailNickname": "MelissaD",
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test1234",
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
  },
  "officeLocation": "131/1105",
  "postalCode": "98052",
  "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
  "state": "WA",
  "streetAddress": "9256 Towne Center Dr., Suite 400",
  "surname": "Darrow",
  "mobilePhone": "+1 206 555 0110",
  "usageLocation": "US",
  "immutableID": "melissab",
  "userPrincipalName": "melissab@example.org"
}
```

What I receive is:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "One or more properties contains invalid values.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "9e8af7a6-fba2-4a66-8421-19dbfd2c36f1",
            "date": "2017-05-12T12:13:22"
        }
    }
}
```

please note `immutableId` can be found in the payload.

Is it possibile to provision such users with the given REST framework?

Answer (score 1):

**immutableID**  must be `Base64` encoded (`byte[]`)

**Ex**:

```
String immutableId = new String(Base64.encodeBase64("someText".getBytes()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. The Graph API does not handle the user sync part. User can be synced using Microsoft Azure Active Directory Sync Tool.

Answer (score 0):

Using graph api you can sync the user from azure to our application.

ex : USER_SYNC_QUERY = **"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$top=100&$count=true"**;

1) On each request graph api will send you a **@odata.nextLink** parameter i.e the skip token for getting next users if more than requested user is present in your azure.

2) By passing the skip token with each request you can sync all the users form azure to your application